# Transit visa for Indian citizen flying to Australia via Hong Kong

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, australia, hong-kong

I am travelling to Australia (Adelaide) on PR (E-Visa) 1st time from India (So do i need any transit visa at Hong Kong & at Perth airport if i stay inside the airport only & my time b/n the connecting flights is less than 8 hrs)

Comment: You never need a transit visa for the country that is your final destination. If Australia is happy for you to visit, they're certainly happy for you to change planes as part of that visit.

Answer (score 0):

As David Richerby stated in his comment, you don't need a transit visa for Perth if you've already got a visa for Australia.

And according to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AU&DV=Australia&TC=HK&TV=Hong%20Kong%2C%20China&h=76befb300a624593628f1784cd61bb0de5f40), you don't need a visa for Hong Kong either if you stay in the transit area:

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward (Air-to-Air or Air-to-Sea) ticket to a third country within 48 hours. They must stay in the international transit area and have documents required for the next destination.